Solutions to system of PDEs, gauge invariance of Lagrangian
Let
$$L = \int \frac{J(a,b)}{2}\dot{x}^2-p(x_a^2+x_b^2-J(a,b)) da da$$
where $p$ is a Lagrange multiplier, $x=x(a,b,t)$ and $dx/dt = \dot{x}$. This Lagrangian corresponds to the following dynamics
$$ x_a^2+x_b^2=J(a,b)$$
and upon eliminating $p$:
$$ x_{at}x_b-x_{bt}x_a = q(a,b).$$
Another way to show that q is independent of $t$ is to note that $L$ stays fixed when we change coordinates: $a\to a-\psi_b, b\to b+\psi_a$ for any $\psi(a,b,t)$, if $\dot{q}=0$. The gauge invariance of the coordinates $(a,b)$ implies this conservation law.
We want to find $x=x(a,b,t)$ so that these two equations are satisfied.
The equations are invariant to the transformation $a\to a-\phi_b \delta t$ and $b\to b+\phi_a\delta t$ for $\phi=1/2(a^2+b^2)$ and some infinitesimal $\delta t$, which induces the transformation
$$x\to x+x_a (-b\delta t)+x_b (a\delta t),$$
which implies a compatability condition:
$$x_{aa}+x_{bb}=0$$
and a time evolution condition
$$ \ddot{x}_a+x_a=0,\ddot{x}_b+x_b=0.$$
$\phi$ is a subset of $\psi$ -- do we expect a connection between these two transformations? That is to say, what other infinitesimal generating functions $\phi$ generate exact solutions?
